Bernstein–von Mises approximation of posterior density, Fisher Information
The Bernstein–von Mises approximation of posterior density theorem, states that certain under conditions,
$$ 
d_{VT} \Big( \Pi(, |X), N \big(\hat{\theta}_n(X), \frac{I(\theta_0)^{-1}}{n} \big) \Big) \to^P 0
$$
Where $d_{VT}$ is the Total variation distance, $\Pi(, |X)$ is the posterior probability
I would like to know if $I(\theta_0)$ corresponds to Fisher's information for one sample or for n samples.
Thank you for your help,
